# How to prevent json hijack on mvc

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

how to prevent json hijack on mvc?

```
[PreventHijack]
public JsonResult Check(int id)
{
   return Json(id, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

javascript

```
$.ajax({
   url: "/Controller/Check?id=1",
   type: "post",
   success: function(data) {
   }
})
```

I don't want anyone to browse this jsonresult through the addressbar.
Is it possible to use the antiforgerytoken here?

Comment: Not sure if there is anything out of the box like this. See this http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You are explicitly allowing users to browse to the URL with `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet`. If you take that out, .NET will throw an error upon hitting that URL: `This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request`

Comment: thanks sweaver2112, the actual jsonresult method's function is to update a database when a user click a checkbox, true or false, that's why i dont want anyone to browse that method with the address bar. is there any other way i can achieve this?

Comment: yes, this is a security feature to prevent such shenanigans.  If you take the allowGet out, and make the button part of a form post (as you have), you should be ok.